# (Phonegap for iphone) Open external links in web-navigator

Tags: iphone, cordova, hyperlink, external

The question it's easy:

How I can open external links (like "_blank") with an app for IPhone made by Phonegap (version 1.4.0)???

I tested a lot of solutions found on internet but without good results...

I can open a link in the same window of app, but I'm interested to open in the web navigator of IPhone (safari?)

Please help me! thank you so much!

(All links have " rel='external' " and " target='_blank' ")

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

In Phonegap.plist file, add * in ExternalHosts

Then External links will be open,
Hope, this'll be useful

Comment: This works BUT don't open in navigator window, it's opened on the same window of app.... I need to open in a new window of a navigator